# How to remove taxonomy with zero posts

Tags: wordpress, tags, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to remove terms/taxonomy which has zero posts. Below is the code, it is throwing error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for second foreach(). Any suggestions?

```
 $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post-type',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
   $q = new WP_Query($terms);

   foreach($q as $term){

    foreach($term as $t) {

       if($t->count == 0)
          wp_delete_term( $t->term_id, 'post-type');
     }
   }`
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `WP_Query` in your code. If your taxonomy is `post-type` the code could look like this.

```php
        $terms = get_terms( [
            'taxonomy'               => 'post-type',
            'hide_empty'             => false,
        ] );

        foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
            if ( 0 === $t->count ) {
                wp_delete_term( $t->term_id, 'post-type' );
            }
        }
```

For a more common taxonomy like `post_tag` it could look like this.

```php
        $terms = get_terms( [
            'taxonomy'               => 'post_tag',
            'hide_empty'             => false,
            'update_term_meta_cache' => false,
            'hierarchical'           => false,
        ] );

        foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
            if ( 0 === $t->count ) {
                wp_delete_term( $t->term_id, 'post_tag' );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change

hide_empty = true 
For example:

```
 $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post-type',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));
```

No need to match with zero count. It will give result with have posts. No worry 100% sure it will work.

Comment: I don't want terms which has posts. I want those terms which do not have posts associated with them i.e terms with zero posts.

Comment: No more option to get zero count post's terms. Your code is right. Use it.